# mouseListener - Implements vs addMouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, implements

I have a JTable and I want to detect a single click and double click on a row. I recognize I need to create a mouseListener. However I have seen examples that extend a JTable and implement a mouseListener as part of the JTable definition, as well as create just a mouse listener and then simply addMouseListener to the JTable. What is the behavior difference and which is the preferred implementation if any? TIA.

Comment: Create the MouseListener and add it to the table.

Comment: Thanks but what is the difference?